# Greasemonkey: POST data causes underscores in float numbers

Tags: json, post, greasemonkey

```
          let jsonString = JSON.stringify(json); 

          console.log(jsonString);  //prints {"5667787":"currentTaxless":99.82,"current":123.78}}                 

          GM.xmlHttpRequest({
            method: "POST",
            url: "https://exampleau.tld",
            data: jsonString,
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            },
            onload: function(response) {
              //stuff
            }
          });
```

Hi,

I am starting to feel myself stupid. I haven't found any way to feed into `data` regular object/array or json, no matter what I did (changed headers, added `dataType`, feed that `json` variable) - the data was not posted. Only this solution posts data. In the Greasemonkey documentation there is nothing about feeding plain json.

The problem is, that on backend, when I receive such a data - it is:

- an array with single key and no value
- the key is `html_entity_encode`(d) string
- **where dots in float numbers are replaced with underscores**. This is what I am getting:

  `{"5667787":{"currentTaxless":99_82,"current":123_78}}`

**Qusetion**: What am I doing wrong or how to post without a hassle or receive normally formatted posted data without a hassle using Greasemonkey???

Versions: `Greasemonkey v4.11`
`Firefox v81`

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.

The solution is not to

`data: jsonString,`,

but rather explicitly put json string under some key as value like this

`data: 'data=' + jsonString,`